# How to get multiple sums that are subqueries

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

Im using Linqpad to test out my EF query and I cant seem to get my end result to include a few extra columns that represent sums of a field based on different conditions

StorePaymentInvoices table contains a FK over to CustomerStatementBatchPayments.  So I need to sum the CustomerStatementBatchPayment.net field if there is a corresponding value in StorePaymentInvoices

Getting the sums is turning out to be a real mess.  Any suggestions?
Sometimes what is hard to do in one statement, ends up being easier done in multiple steps.

```
var retval = (
            from a in CustomerStatementBatches 
            join b in CustomerStatementBatchPayments on a.ID equals b.CustomerStatementBatchID into grp1
            from c in grp1              
            where a.CustomerStatementID == StatementId 
            group c by c.CustomerStatementBatchID into grp2
            from e in grp2              
            select new { 
                StatementId = e.CustomerStatementBatch.CustomerStatementID,
                BatchId = e.CustomerStatementBatchID,
                Applied =  CustomerStatementBatchPayments.Where(csbp => !StorePaymentInvoices.Select (pi => pi.CustomerStatementBatchPaymentID ).ToList().Contains(e.ID)).Sum (csbp => csbp.Net )
            }
            ).ToList();
retval.Dump();
```

**[ UPDATE  1]**
This is what Ive done to get the "conditional" sum values and I seem to be getting the correct numbers.  The resulting SQL that it generates is kinda ugly, but executes in < 1 second.

```
    var retval1 = (
            from a in CustomerStatementBatches 
            join b in CustomerStatementBatchPayments on a.ID equals b.CustomerStatementBatchID into grp1
            from c in grp1              
            where a.CustomerStatementID == StatementId 
            group c by new { a.CustomerStatementID, c.CustomerStatementBatchID} into grp2
            from e in grp2.Distinct()
            select new { 
                StatementId = e.CustomerStatementBatch.CustomerStatementID,
                BatchId = e.CustomerStatementBatchID
            }
            ).ToList()
            .Distinct()
            .Select(a => new 
            {
                StatementId = a.StatementId, 
                BatchId = a.BatchId,
                AppliedTotal = (from b in CustomerStatementBatchPayments.Where(r => r.CustomerStatementBatchID == a.BatchId) 
                                join c in StorePaymentInvoices on b.ID equals c.CustomerStatementBatchPaymentID                                                                     
                                group b by b.CustomerStatementBatchID into g1 
                                from d in g1
                                select new{ Total = (decimal?)d.Net}).DefaultIfEmpty().Sum (at => (decimal?)at.Total ) ?? 0.0m,
                Unappliedtotal = (from b in CustomerStatementBatchPayments.Where(r => r.CustomerStatementBatchID == a.BatchId) 
                                .Where(s => !StorePaymentInvoices.Any (pi => pi.CustomerStatementBatchPaymentID == s.ID ) )
                                select new{ Total = (decimal?)b.Net}).DefaultIfEmpty().Sum (at => (decimal?)at.Total ) ?? 0.0m                                  
            })
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from a in db.CustomerStatementBatches 
join b in db.CustomerStatementBatchPayments
            //.Where(i => ...)
            .GroupBy(i => i.CustomerStatementBatchesId)
            .Select(i => new { 
                                CustomerStatementBatchesId = i.Key,
                                SumOfPayments = i.Sum(t => t.Net)
                             }
                    ) 
           into tmp from b in tmp.DefaultIfEmpty() 
       on a.CustomerStatementBatchesId equals b.CustomerStatementBatchesId 
select new
{
    StatementId = a.CustomerStatementId,
    BatchId = a.CustomerStatementBatchId,
    Applied =  ((b == null) ? 0 : b.SumOfPayments)
}
```

Comment: See the original post again.  Im trying to do the sum on those records where there isnt a FK match in StorePaymentInvoices. In other words, I need to do a conditional sum.  With TSQL it would be a subquery using "not exists".  Also need a 2nd field in the results that would be "where exists" in tsql.  Hope that makes sense.  Im going to see if I can split this up into smaller statements, but Im curious if I can do it in one.

Comment: Write that conditon to `where clauase`? let me know it worked

Comment: I added an update to the original post.  I think I got it after a lot of grief, but I knew it was going to be messy.